# IOS Coredata Autofill textfield with searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextfield

I am working on coredatabase project and implementing Text-field autofill search functionality. I am new to coredata. so, i can't understand how to get result of searched text in Autofilltableview and how to use Nspredicate to search the string from coredata..

Here is my try:

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
    replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if (textField==_textField1) {
            [popupView bringSubviewToFront:autocompleteTableView];
            [autocompleteTableView setHidden:NO];

            NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
            substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    }
            return YES;
            //[popupView bringSubviewToFront:autoCompleteTextField];

            //[self searchedbuttonclcked ];



    }


        - (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

        //searcharray=[NSMutableArray new];
        AppDelegate *appdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *contex;
        contex=[appdelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                       entityForName:@"Iw" inManagedObjectContext:contex];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
         NSError *error;
        NSArray *queryArray;
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@",self.textField1.text];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        queryArray = [contex executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

      [autocompleteTableView reloadData]; // This is tableview which contains result below the textfield 
    }

    #pragma mark -->Autocomplete tablevie methods
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        id  sectionInfo =
        [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    }

    - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      //  _searchfetch  = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        NSManagedObject *fetchsidename = [self.searchfetch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [fetchsidename valueForKey:@"name"]]];

       }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    }
```

[image: Autofill tableview]

Comment: Do you ever use `queryArray` for anything?

Comment: nope. I am trying to use query array to store search result.

Comment: As Wain indicated, you are doing a search, and then just throwing away the results.  The rest of the code is using a FRC, which has nothing to do with the fetch request in searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring